# Помогите пожалуйста. Что не так?

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T>
class TypeName
{
public:
    TypeName(T value)
    {
        this->value = value;
    }
    void GetClassSize()
    {
        cout << (sizeof(value)) << endl;
    }
protected:
    T value;
};

template<typename T>
class TypeInfo : public TypeName<T>
{
public:
    TypeInfo(T value) :TypeName(value)
    {
    }
    void GetTypeName()
    {
        cout << "Name type: " << typeid(value).name() << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    Point pnt(1,3,4);
    int a = 1;
    TypeInfo<int> c(a);
    c.GetClassSize();
    c.GetTypeName();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не так - заголовок. Как другие поймут, стоит ли им заходить, есть ли там решение по их проблеме? Напишите адекватное название.

Comment: В чем вопрос? Что такое "не так"???

Comment: Лучше сразу говорить, что с кодом не так. Если это ошибка компиляции, приводите текст ошибки дословно. Не надо убирать инклюды и `using namespace std;` (нам ведь их придется дописывать, если мы захотим проверить код).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое: При вызове конструктора родителя нужно указать еще и его шаблонные параметры.

Вместо `TypeInfo(T value) : TypeName(value)`
Нужно `TypeInfo(T value) : TypeName<T>(value)`

Второе: Раз родитель - шаблон, то к его полям нельзя так просто обратиться. ([Подробнее.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567730/inheritance-and-templates-in-c-why-are-methods-invisible))

Вместо `cout << "Name type: " << typeid(value).name() << endl;`
Нужно либо `cout << "Name type: " << typeid(this->value).name() << endl;`
Либо `cout << "Name type: " << typeid(TypeName<T>::value).name() << endl;`

---

Кроме того, из `main` надо выбросить `Point pnt(1,3,4);`, который вообще непонятно зачем нужен.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогло.